# superseding css style in list

Tags: html, css

I have a style for paragraph as

```
<div id="content">
   Text
   <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
   </ul>
</div>

#content{
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 18px;
}
```

However, this style does not apply to the list. What can be done to rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML (as written in the **original** question) is invalid. You cannot have a list inside a paragraph. Browsers tend to error correct by inserting `</p>` before `<ul>` and then ignoring the `</p>` after the `</ul>`.

You probably want something like:

```
<div id="content">
   <p>Text</p>
   <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Its actually a div tag not a paragraph, sorry

Comment: Then it will apply, unless you have another style overriding it for the `<ul>` or `<li>`. You need to identify that style and override it in turn (with a more specific selector).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ul#content
{
    place styles here...
}
```

to affect your unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an id (instead of a [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)), make sure you have only one thing marked as "content" in the HTML.  Some browsers seem to handle this okay, but some may not.

The following is working for me using Firefox 3.6.17 and Chromium 11.0 on Ubuntu.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #content {
       font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
       font-size: 12px;
       line-height: 18px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      Text
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```