# List is not inheriting style of outer div's CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a list inside a div. The div is styled as

```
<div id="container">
Random text
<ul>
   <li>Text</li>
</ul>
<div>

#container{
//styling information
}
```

However, the list is not following the style of the container. How can I fix this?

Comment: Should go to StackOverflow, wait for it to be migrated there!

Comment: possible duplicate of [superseding css style in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979582/superseding-css-style-in-list)

Comment: what do you mean `it's not following the style?` What is it not doing? Can you add some code or better yet link to a sample page?

Comment: @DavidDorward for a minute there, I thought you had psychic powers to be able to figure out what he wanted. Then I noticed the OP of the question you linked to :D

Comment: Phew. For a moment there I thought my psychic cover identity had been blown!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
#container ul{
//styling information
}
```

to style the list and

```
#container li{
//styling information
}
```

to style the items